# Line chart from json response in html / javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a **single line chart** of a json response(sql) in html/javascript. What im trying to create is a chart with only **one** line of the tag_name, in the case below: "phone 4". This line should represent all values and datetimes of all json strings.

JSON response:

```
[{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:20:09"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:19:49"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:19:29"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:19:09"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:18:49"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:18:29"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:18:09"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:17:49"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:17:29"},
{"tag_name":"phone 4","value":"4","datetime":"2017-10-03 14:17:09"}]
```

What i've reached so far(not much):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
             var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             data.addColumn('number', 'Datetime');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Values');

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Values',
                },
                width: 900,
                height: 500
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
        }
</script>
```

How my php code looks like:

```
 require_once 'db_connection.php';
 header('Content-type: application/json');

 $data = array();
 $Chart = "SELECT *
             FROM (
                  SELECT *,
                  @rn := if( @tag_name = tag_name,
                   @rn + 1,
                   if(@tag_name := tag_name, 1, 1)
                ) as tag_count
            FROM waardes 
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @tag_name := '') as vars
            ORDER BY tag_name
        ) as T          
      WHERE tag_count < 11 AND machine_id LIKE 3 AND tag_name LIKE 'phone 4'
      ORDER BY datetime DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $Chart);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     if ($row["int_value"] == 0 && $row["real_value"] == 0.0 && $row["bool_value"] != "") {
    array_push($data, array('tag_name' => $row['tag_name'], 'value' => $row['bool_value'], 'datetime' => $row['datetime']));
} elseif ($row["int_value"] == 0 && $row["real_value"] != 0 && $row["bool_value"] == "") {
    array_push($data, array('tag_name' => $row['tag_name'], 'value' => $row['real_value'], 'datetime' => $row['datetime']));
} elseif ($row["int_value"] != 0 && $row["real_value"] == 0 && $row["bool_value"] == "") {
    array_push($data, array('tag_name' => $row['tag_name'], 'value' => $row['int_value'], 'datetime' => $row['datetime']));
}
}

 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9goOKclCWjI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, don't recommend mixing php and javascript in the same file

separate the html / javascript from the php

use ajax to get the data from php to javascript

for google charts, use the json format found here...
[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

this will allow you to create the google data table, directly from the json

**getdata.php**

```
require_once 'db_connection.php';
header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = array();
$Chart = "SELECT *
             FROM (
                  SELECT *,
                  @rn := if( @tag_name = tag_name,
                   @rn + 1,
                   if(@tag_name := tag_name, 1, 1)
                ) as tag_count
            FROM waardes
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @tag_name := '') as vars
            ORDER BY tag_name
        ) as T
      WHERE tag_count < 11 AND machine_id LIKE 3 AND tag_name LIKE 'phone 4'
      ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $Chart);


$data = array();
$data['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'phone 4', 'type' => 'number')
);
$data['rows'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row["int_value"] == 0 && $row["real_value"] == 0.0 && $row["bool_value"] != "") {

      $row = array();
      $row[] = array('v' => (string) $row['datetime']);
      $row[] = array('v' => (float) $row['bool_value']);
      $data['rows'][] = array('c' => $row);

  } elseif ($row["int_value"] == 0 && $row["real_value"] != 0 && $row["bool_value"] == "") {

      $row = array();
      $row[] = array('v' => (string) $row['datetime']);
      $row[] = array('v' => (float) $row['real_value']);
      $data['rows'][] = array('c' => $row);

  } elseif ($row["int_value"] != 0 && $row["real_value"] == 0 && $row["bool_value"] == "") {

      $row = array();
      $row[] = array('v' => (string) $row['datetime']);
      $row[] = array('v' => (float) $row['int_value']);
      $data['rows'][] = array('c' => $row);

  }
}

$data['rows'] = $rows;

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['line']
}).then(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getdata.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (jsonData) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Values'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));

    }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
      console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
    });

});
```

---

this will give you a better structure to handle multiple charts / data tables

now, if you wanted to use a real date in the chart, instead of a string (as in the above php)
it would allow you to use chart options such as `format`, for the x-axis

you can pass the date value as a string, in the following format found here...
[Dates and Times Using the Date String Representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)

`"Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)"`

to do this, change the column type to date...

```
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
```

then when loading the data, using the following to format as above...

```
      $rowDate = "Date(".date_format($row['datetime'], 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($row['datetime'], 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($row['datetime'], 'd').", ".date_format($row['datetime'], 'H').", ".date_format($row['datetime'], 'i').", ".date_format($row['datetime'], 's').")";

      $row = array();
      $row[] = array('v' => (string) $rowDate);
      $row[] = array('v' => (float) $row['bool_value']);
      $data['rows'][] = array('c' => $row);
```

note: month numbers are zero-based in javascript...